# Spring-batch facing issue after upgrading version from 3.x.x to 4.x.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-batch

```xml
<bean id="xxx"
class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader">
</bean>
```

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xxx' defined in class path resource [xxx.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.batch.core.resource.ListPreparedStatementSetter#5fe1ce85' of type [org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'preparedStatementSetter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.batch.core.resource.ListPreparedStatementSetter#5fe1ce85#1' defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [xxx.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.batch.core.resource.ListPreparedStatementSetter] for bean with name 'scopedTarget.org.springframework.batch.core.resource.ListPreparedStatementSetter#5fe1ce85' defined in class path resource [xxx.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.batch.core.resource.ListPreparedStatementSetter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:95)
    at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.job.XXXJobLauncher.main(XXXJobLauncher.java:81)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.batch.core.resource.ListPreparedStatementSetter#5fe1ce85#1' defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [xxx.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.batch.core.resource.ListPreparedStatementSetter] for bean with name 'scopedTarget.org.springframework.batch.core.resource.ListPreparedStatementSetter#5fe1ce85' defined in class path resource [xxx.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.batch.core.resource.ListPreparedStatementSetter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:374)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.batch.core.resource.ListPreparedStatementSetter] for bean with name 'scopedTarget.org.springframework.batch.core.resource.ListPreparedStatementSetter#5fe1ce85' defined in class path resource [xxx.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.batch.core.resource.ListPreparedStatementSetter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:704)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:674)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getType(AbstractBeanFactory.java:722)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getType(AbstractBeanFactory.java:683)
    at org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyFactoryBean.setBeanFactory(ScopedProxyFactoryBean.java:100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1826)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1791)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.batch.core.resource.ListPreparedStatementSetter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:469)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1607)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1534)
```

Comment: Based on the answer below: Duplicate of [how to replace the code which has deprecated classes](/q/68642471/4642212).

Answer (score 1):

Replacing org.springframework.batch.core.resource.ListPreparedStatementSette with org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter in xml configuration did the trick.